# What does a lock statement do under the hood?

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, locking, thread-safety

I see that for using objects which are not thread safe we wrap the code with a lock like this:

```
private static readonly Object obj = new Object();

lock (obj)
{
    // thread unsafe code
}
```

So, what happens when multiple threads access the same code (let's assume that it is running in a ASP.NET web application). Are they queued? If so how long will they wait?

What is the performance impact because of using locks?

Comment: ^ dead link, see: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/index.html

Answer (score 535, accepted):

The `lock` statement is translated by C# 3.0 to the following:

```
var temp = obj;

Monitor.Enter(temp);

try
{
    // body
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(temp);
}
```

In C# 4.0 [this has changed](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/) and it is now generated as follows:

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var temp = obj;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken);
    // body
}
finally
{
    if (lockWasTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(temp); 
    }
}
```

You can find more info about what `Monitor.Enter` does [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.enter#System_Threading_Monitor_Enter_System_Object_). To quote MSDN:

> Use `Enter` to acquire the Monitor on
>   the object passed as the parameter. If
>   another thread has executed an `Enter`
>   on the object but has not yet executed
>   the corresponding `Exit`, the current
>   thread will block until the other
>   thread releases the object. It is
>   legal for the same thread to invoke
>   `Enter` more than once without it
>   blocking; however, an equal number of
>   `Exit` calls must be invoked before
>   other threads waiting on the object
>   will unblock.

The `Monitor.Enter` method will wait infinitely; it will *not* time out.

Comment: According to MSDN 

"Using the lock (C#) or SyncLock (Visual Basic) keyword is generally preferred over using the Monitor class directly, both because lock or SyncLock is more concise, and because lock or SyncLock insures that the underlying monitor is released, even if the protected code throws an exception. This is accomplished with the finally keyword, which executes its associated code block regardless of whether an exception is thrown."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx

Comment: What's the point of the var temp = obj; line.  since it's just a ref to begin with, what good does making another one do?

Comment: @priehl It allows the user to change `obj` without the whole system to deadlock.

Comment: Just another syntactic sugar?

Comment: @Joymon eventually, every language feature is syntactic sugar. Language features are about about making developers more productive and making applications more maintainable, as is the lock feature as well.

Comment: Does this mean that if you use the same "object" for the lock in different methods, no matter what method a thread hits, if there is another thread executing another method with the same "object" used in the lock, the thread has to wait until the "object" is released? I appreciate your time.

Comment: Correct. This is the entire purpose of the `lock`-statement and Monitor: so that you can perform an operation in one thread without having to worry about another thread mucking it up.

Answer (score 349):

Its simpler than you think-

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx):
The `lock` keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.

The `lock` keyword calls [`Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.enter.aspx) at the start of the block and [`Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.exit.aspx) at the end of the block. `lock` keyword actually handles [`Monitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Monitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class at back end.

For example:

```
private static readonly Object obj = new Object();

lock (obj)
{
    // critical section
}
```

In the above code, first the thread enters a critical section, and then it will lock `obj`. When another thread tries to enter, it will also try to lock `obj`, which is already locked by the first thread. Second thread will have to wait for the first thread to release `obj`. When the first thread leaves, then another thread will lock `obj` and will enter the critical section.

Comment: should we create a dummy object to lock or can we lock an existing variable in the context?

Comment: @batmaci - Locking on a separate private dummy object gives you a guarantee that no one else is locking in that object. If you lock on the data and that same piece of data is visible to the outside you lose that guarantee.

Comment: What happens if more than one process is waiting for the lock to release? Are the waiting processes queued so that they will be lock the critical section in FIFO order?

Comment: @jstuardo - They are queued, but the order is not guaranteed to be FIFO.

Check out this link: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx

Comment: Copied without attribution from http://net-informations.com/faq/qk/lock.htm

Answer (score 58):

No, they are not queued, they are sleeping

A lock statement of the form

```
lock (x) ...
```

where x is an expression of a reference-type, is precisely equivalent to

```
var temp = x;
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(temp); 
try { ... } 
finally { System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(temp); }
```

You just need to know that they are waiting to each other, and only one thread will enter to lock block, the others will wait...

Monitor is written fully in .net so it is enough fast, also look at  [class Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) with [reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) for more details

Comment: Note that the code emitted for the `lock` statement changed slightly in C#4: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, they are not kept in "Blocked" state "Queue?. I think there are some difference between Sleep and block state, is not it?

Comment: what difference you mean @Mohanavel?

Comment: What happens if more than one process is waiting for the lock to release? Are the waiting processes queued so that they will be lock the critical section in FIFO order?

Comment: @jstuardo, lock or monitor is not visible outside of process... it make sense only for threads in the single process... for processes Mutex, Semaphore or other Windows Core objects can be used...

Comment: That was not the question. The question was regarding "lock" keyword. Suppose a process enter a "lock" section. That means that process blocks that piece of code and no other process may be able to enter that section until that lock is released. Well.... now, 2 more processes try to enter the same block. Since it is protected by "lock" keyword, they will wait, according to what was said in this forum. When the first process releases the lock. What process enters the block? the first one that tried to enter or the last one?

Comment: I guess you mean thread instead of process... if so, than the answer is No, there is no guarantee which one will enter... more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228864/does-lock-guarantee-acquired-in-order-requested

Answer (score 38):

Locks will block other threads from executing the code contained in the lock block.  The threads will have to wait until the thread inside the lock block has completed and the lock is released.  This does have a negative impact on performance in a multithreaded environment.  If you do need to do this you should make sure the code within the lock block can process very quickly.  You should try to avoid expensive activities like accessing a database etc.

Answer (score 13):

The performance impact depends on the way you lock. You can find a good list of optimizations here: http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/07/31/10-ways-to-reduce-lock-contention-in-threaded-programs/

Basically you should try to lock as little as possible, since it puts your waiting code to sleep. If you have some heavy calculations or long lasting code (e.g. file upload) in a lock it results in a huge performance loss.

Comment: But trying to write low-lock code can often result in subtle, hard-to-find-and-fix bugs, even if you're an expert in the field. Using a lock is often the lesser of two evils. You should lock exactly as much as you need to, no more, no less!

Comment: @LukeH: There are some usage patterns where low-lock code can be very simple and easy [`do { oldValue = thing; newValue = updated(oldValue); } while (CompareExchange(ref thing, newValue, oldValue) != oldValue`].  The biggest danger is that if the requirements evolve beyond what such techniques can be handle, it may be hard to adapt the code to handle that.

Comment: Link has broken.

Answer (score 10):

The part within the lock statement can only be executed by one thread, so all other threads will wait indefinitely for it the thread holding the lock to finish. This can result in a so-called deadlock.

Answer (score 9):

The `lock` statement is translated to calls to the `Enter` and `Exit` methods of [`Monitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx).

The `lock` statement will wait indefinitely for the locking object to be released.

Answer (score 4):

[lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is actually hidden [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft's MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement), the lock is equivalent to:

```cs
object __lockObj = x;
bool __lockWasTaken = false;
try
{
    System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(__lockObj, ref __lockWasTaken);
    // Your code...
}
finally
{
    if (__lockWasTaken) System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(__lockObj);
}
```

If you need to create locks in runtime, you can use open source [DynaLock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynaLock). You can create new locks in run-time and specify boundaries to the locks with context concept.

DynaLock is open-source and source code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/saeedmaghdam/DynaLock)