# Ado.Net transaction lock

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, locking, e-commerce

I am working on `e-commerce` application, I have three tables in DB

1. Customer
2. Order
3. Order Details

`Order Details` information about individual products and `OrderId` that is primary key of `Order` and I have 2 `Stored Procedures`

1. InsertIntoOrderAndCustomer
2. InsertIntoOrderDetails

as `InsertIntoOrderAndCustomer` is called from `ADO.Net` it will generate `autoid` `OrderId` in `Order` and I need to use that id in as a parameter to `InsertIntoOrderDetails` but I am worried if multiple orders are being placed then parameter value may be wrong. Can I lock `C#` code so that only one order will be placed at a time? If yes, then how?

**I am worried about**

2 Persons placing order

Execution could be,

Person A places order

1. Insert data into Orders table for Person A - It will generate id automatically `IDENTITY` (of course only once).

Mean while Person B places order then

1. Insert data into Orders table for Person B - It will generate id automatically `IDENTITY` (different one).

then insert data into `product details` table with AutoId `IDENTITY` in Orders table.

While inserting into `product details` I am getting auto id using `MAX` of `SQL Server` and this will give me 101, as in above scenario.

Is there possibility that second insert put `IDENTITY` of `Order` of Person B (i.e 101) and other data of Person `A` ? it worries me.

Comment: Why would the parameter value be wrong?

Comment: You can use a `lock` in C# like explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6029804/2132796). However, you should reconsider doing this. As @MarcGravell mentioned, why would it be wrong?

Comment: If 2 persons are placing order, and 2 sp are being called for both orders. Person A put the request and suppose its auto generated OrderId 100, at the same time person B put another and its OrderId is 101. To call second SP, OrderId of `A' can be passed in `B`'s second sp because of I/O waiting and all, I am not sure, can it be? I am just worried of future bugs, so...

Comment: @Herdo `lock` is usually useless when talking about databases, as they are *usually* accessed by multiple proceses

Comment: @SMI why would it auto-generate OrderId 100 twice at the same time? What "autoid" are you using here? If this is SQL Server `IDENTITY`, it will never generate the same id twice. Frankly, unless you are rolling your own (and buggy) auto-id, it should work fine. So: how is your "autoid" working here?

Comment: @MarcGravell I know. But he asked for a C# lock. And as mentioned, he should reconsider doing so.

Comment: @Herdo which to me would mean "lock the table"; frankly, a regular sql transaction should work fine here even if doing everything manually, if the isolation level is high enough (serializable would take x-range locks; might need some UPDLOCK to avoid deadlock, though). But frankly the real "fix" here is: use the database's inbuilt automatic id generation.

Comment: @SMI what is the database here, and how are you implementing this auto-id?

Comment: May be my poor explanation not helping me to clarify, yet I made last attempt and edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the potential for mixup is coming from "I am getting auto id using `MAX` of Sql Server".
If you are calling both stored procedures from C# code and are calling them independently, and the second sproc (`InsertIntoOrderDetails`) relies on `MAX` to get the last auto-generated id from `Orders`, then yes, this is subject to getting the Id from user A or B mixed up in the OrderDetails table.

I can suggest three approaches. There might be others:

1. Return the auto-generated id from Orders as a Return or Output parameter of `InsertIntoOrderAndCustomer`. using `scope_identity()` Use it as an input parameter when calling the second sproc `InsertIntoOrderDetails`. The c# code should be aware of which customer and orders details are in context.
2. Have the `InsertIntoOrderAndCustomer` sproc capture the auto-generated id (using `scope_identity` and then also call the `InsertIntoOrderDetails` directly itself.
3. I don't recommend this, but since you asked. Your c# code could use a `EventWaitHandle` to allow the procedure code to be called only once at a time. This is not scalable, and it also does not prohibit mixup using your existing approach if the procedures are called outside of the c# world.