# how to handle 3 threads accessing the same function in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am developing one small excel application , in which i have three threads accessing the same function. I want that function must be accessed by one thread when other thread is done. can some one help me in this. below code i tried.

```
              if ((checkBox1.Checked == true) && (textBox2.Text != ""))
                {
                    Run_thread = new Thread(() => READ_MAPPING_FILE_PATHS(textBox2.Text, 5, 15));
                    Run_thread.Start();

                }
                if ((checkBox2.Checked == true) && (textBox5.Text != ""))
                {
                    Run_thread1 = new Thread(() => READ_MAPPING_FILE_PATHS(textBox5.Text, 7, 9));
                    Run_thread1.Start();
                    //READ_MAPPING_FILE_PATHS(textBox5.Text, 7, 9);
                    check++;
                }
                if ((checkBox3.Checked == true) && (textBox6.Text != ""))
                {
                   Run_thread2 = new Thread(() => READ_MAPPING_FILE_PATHStextBox6.Text, 5, 15);
                    Run_thread.Start(); 
                }
```

//function definition which is accessed by threads.

```
    public void READ_MAPPING_FILE_PATHS(string path , int A429, int ACSB)
    {
        // do something
     }
```

i tried using AutoResetEvent event property to handle but this leads to my application on not responding mode.

```
AutoResetEvent myResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

  waitHandle.WaitOne();

 waitHandle.Set();
```

Comment: using `lock`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029804/how-does-lock-work-exactly

Comment: @user3185569 in my case i am not using any object based locking..

Comment: And Why you're not doing that ? Being the simplest recommended approach that leads to the required results.

Comment: ok let me try this..will be back in case i have any queries..

Comment: Why use threads if they should block each other? If you don't want to block the gui, you might try a BackgroundWorkerThread which consumes a queue of workitems. This way you can handle multiple files, which do not run simultain but doesn't block the gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `lock` :

```
static object _lock = new object();
public void READ_MAPPING_FILE_PATHS(string path , int A429, int ACSB)
{
   lock(_lock)
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: @SanjeevKumar I see this as the most elegant, clear and concise way of doing it.