# Is there a syntactic sugar in C# similar to `using()` except for taking waiting and releasing on a semaphore?

Tags: c#, language-features, syntactic-sugar

`using (var foo = bar){}` is excellent syntactic sugar. It replaces an entire blob

```
var foo = bar
try
{
}
finally
{
    foo.dispose()
}
```

I found myself today writing very similar blobs

```
var foo.WaitOne();
try
{
}
finally
{
    foo.release()
}
```

I don't suppose there is similar sugar for this in C#?

Comment: Sorry for offtop, but there is a `lock` for `Monitor`, maybe it will be usable in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As adviced by Alexei, your best chance is to mock the requested behavior using an helper class which implements `IDisposable`.

Something like this should suffice:

```
public static class AutoReleaseSemaphoreExtensions
{
    // single threaded + idempotent Dispose version
    private sealed class AutoReleaseSemaphore : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Semaphore _semaphore;

        private bool _disposed = false;

        public AutoReleaseSemaphore(Semaphore semaphore)
        {
            _semaphore = semaphore;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if(_disposed) return;
            _semaphore.Release();
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable WaitOneAndRelease(this Semaphore semaphore)
    {
        semaphore.WaitOne();
        return new AutoReleaseSemaphore(semaphore);
    }
}
```

Which may be used in the following way (thanks to extension methods):

```
var sem = new Semaphore(0, 1); // your semaphore here

using (sem.WaitOneAndRelease())
{
    // do work here
}
// semaphore is released outside using block.
```

Comment: This could be improved by ensuring that `Dispose` is idempotent.  Right now if `Dispose` gets called multiple times, the semaphore will get released multiple times.  Something like `public void Dispose() { var s = Interlocked.Exchange( ref _semaphore, null ); s?.Release(); }` and making sure `_semaphore` is not readonly.

Comment: @Kyle you are certainly right. We may also avoid the use of any lock (or `Interlocked` call) by just implicitly restrict its usage inside a single thread (which, I believe, is the right thing to do). This way a simple `bool _disposed` field should be enough.

Comment: I've seen this pattern elsewhere too. Leveraging the `using` keyword by boilerplating your (er, boilerplate) code into IDisposables is really, really, sweet. I mean that in a purely platonic and syntactic way.

Answer (score 3):

No.  There is one for `Monitor` ([`lock`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029804/how-does-lock-work-exactly)) but none for semaphore.

If you really want you can create helper disposable class to use it with `using` but it may be considered abuse of `IDisposable` pattern.

Comment: I thought as much. I'll weigh if it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [lock statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.90).aspx).

`lock` calls `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`, but it's the only syntactic sugar blob-replacer related to thread synchronization.

The answer to this question expands it very well: [How does lock work exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029804/how-does-lock-work-exactly/6029819)

Comment: Lock is for mutexes, not semaphores.