# Monitor.TryEnter()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

I was wondering on the Monitor Class.
As far as i know all waiting threads are not FIFO.
The first one that aquires the lock is not allways the first on in the waiting queue.
Is this correct? 
Is there some way to ensure the FIFO condition?

Regards

Comment: Good question. Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111779/lock-monitor-internal-implementation-in-net

Comment: Why does fifo matter? Since you can't really guarantee the order in which the threads will arrive. Also with asynchronous call procedures (APC) you can't even guarantee a waiting thread won't be borrowed for a moment to service a callback before returning to wait on the lock.

Comment: @ChrisChilvers FIFO can matter a lot! So much so that Microsoft have now introduced locks which guarantee FIFO behaviour.

Comment: @adelphus I agree. Can you point me which locks guarantee FIFO behavior??

Comment: Not in .NET I'm afraid. The locks I was talking about are in kernel-mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559970(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this question, I think it will very useful for you - [Does lock() guarantee acquired in order requested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228864/does-lock-guarantee-acquired-in-order-requested)

especially this quote:

> Because monitors use kernel objects internally, they exhibit the same
>   roughly-FIFO behavior that the OS synchronization mechanisms also
>   exhibit (described in the previous chapter). Monitors are unfair, so
>   if another thread tries to acquire the lock before an awakened waiting
>   thread tries to acquire the lock, the sneaky thread is permitted to
>   acquire a lock.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to a built-in way, then no. Repeatedly calling `TryEnter` in a loop is by definition not fair and unfortunately neither is the simple `Monitor.Enter`. Technically a thread could wait forever without getting the lock.

If you want absolute fairness you will need to implement it yourself using a queue to keep track of arrival order.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some way to ensure the FIFO condition?

In a word: no!

I wrote a short article about this: [Is the Ready Queue FIFO?](http://www.nickbutler.net/Article/ReadyQueue)