# What is the invocation sequence of awaiting threads after lock released

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking

Assume that I have following function:

```
public void AddItems(List<Item> items)
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {                   
            Buffer.Enqueue(item);                    
        }
    }
}
```

This function can be invoked from many different threads.

The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Although locks ensures that received items do no mix with each other I would like to know what is the invocation sequence of awaiting threads after lock released.

Comment: *"I would like to what is the invocation sequence of awaiting threads after lock released."* You mean, which thread will get the handle of the lock first?

Comment: yes, precisely as you wrote

Comment: Then see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228864/does-lock-guarantee-acquired-in-order-requested) question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Closed before a minute :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Are you hacking my computer? :P

Comment: Each thread should have its own await event so only the thread that invoke the AddItems gets notified that the item got added.