# C# Thread and lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I test simple code

```
    static Thread _readThread = null;
    static private Object thisLock = new Object();
    static int a = 1;

    private static void ReadComPort()
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "  " + a++.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            _readThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadComPort));
            _readThread.IsBackground = true;
            _readThread.Name = i.ToString();
            _readThread.Start();
            //Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

but why is the sequence of execution and the launching of threads chaotic:
0,2,1 Why?

Console output:

```
0  1
End
0  2
0  3
2  4
2  5
2  6
1  7
1  8
1  9
```

Comment: What were you *expecting* and *why*? Note that your low iteration counts mean that any interactions *between* threads are unlikely.

Comment: When a thread is started it is not guaranteed to run immediately nor in the order of being started compared to other threads

Comment: You can use `Task.ContinueWith`, queue to run threads, queue/priority to synchronize access to Console, what else.. should be more, but definitely not running some threads and expecting them to organize themselves as you didn't tell them to...

Comment: Well, you don't want more than 1 thread pulling your ComPort anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't expect threads to start or run in a specific order. The OS schedules threads the way it wants to. Sometimes it puts a thread on hold, executes another one, before coming back to the original one.

Here you see that the threads start almost at the same time. Obviously (from the output) thread 0 wins it to the first lock. Then, by pure chance, thread 2 gets by the lock earlier than thread 1. This could have gone entirely different since the threads are created shortly after each other. As said: there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

Lock does not guarantee the order : [Does lock() guarantee acquired in order requested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228864/does-lock-guarantee-acquired-in-order-requested)

Also, in your code, you should wait your threads to finish at the end of your for loop in order to not have "end" at the beginning - if you press a key, you will exit while your thread are still running, and you may have unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Read the C# reference carefully.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

There, you cannot find anything about the order of threads entering the lock block.