# TPL dataflow feedback loop

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

The pipeline takes absolute path of file (in `Block 1`) and processes it and saves it to database (in `block3`).

The constraint is that certain file types (*.vde)  depend on a particular parent file type (*.vd). The parent file type has the metadata required to process the dependent file types. Unless the parent file type is present in the system, I cannot process the dependent file type.

Objective - I need the system to somehow wait for the parent file type to enter the system and update the state. Then the dependent file types are automatically called upon again and processed.

My approach - Add a feedback loop (`block 4`) which is linked to `block 1`.
However, **I end up losing the messages. The messages coming from `block 4` to `block 1` are not able to reach `block 3` and are lost in between somewhere in the pipeline.**

What can I do to not lose the messages coming from `block 4` to `block 1`?

Or can this be done in a better way?

[image: Pipeline for Data Processing]

Comment: What do you mean by `messages are lost`? TPL won't 'lose' messages, more likely your code stops the flow somewhere.

Also, i'd recommend exiting TPL altogether. When you get your files in Block 1 and detect that they're .vde, check if .vd is present. If so, process. If not, add it to a `ConcurrentQueue` or some other concurrent collection. Then, when .vd enters Block 4 or whatever the final is, you can push messages back to block 1 for any .vde in your Concurrent Collection

Comment: Can you provide the code for the dataflow? It's not clear what you mean by _messages are lost_.

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise I attempted to make a `JoinDependencyBlock` similar to the [`JoinBlock<T1,T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.joinblock-2), that propagates matching elements from two buffers.

---

**Update**: I came up with a simpler implementation, that uses internally three build-in blocks, two `ActionBlock`s for input and one `BufferBlock` for output. Each action block populates a dedicated `List`, and when an element is added the two lists are searched for matched pairs. If one is found it is posted to the `BufferBlock`. The main complexity is at the linking of these blocks, because the success and failure cases need different handling.

When the `JoinDependencyBlock` is completed, any unmatched elements in the internal lists are discarded.

```
public class JoinDependencyBlock<T1, T2> : ISourceBlock<(T1, T2)>
{
    private readonly Func<T1, T2, bool> _matchPredicate;
    private readonly List<T1> _list1 = new List<T1>();
    private readonly List<T2> _list2 = new List<T2>();
    private readonly ActionBlock<T1> _input1;
    private readonly ActionBlock<T2> _input2;
    private readonly BufferBlock<(T1, T2)> _output;
    private readonly object _locker = new object();

    public JoinDependencyBlock(Func<T1, T2, bool> matchPredicate,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _matchPredicate = matchPredicate
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(matchPredicate));

        // Create the three internal blocks
        var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            CancellationToken = cancellationToken
        };
        _input1 = new ActionBlock<T1>(Add1, options);
        _input2 = new ActionBlock<T2>(Add2, options);
        _output = new BufferBlock<(T1, T2)>(options);

        // Link the input blocks with the output block
        var inputTasks = new Task[] { _input1.Completion, _input2.Completion };
        Task.WhenAny(inputTasks).Unwrap().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // If ANY input block fails, then the whole block has failed
            ((IDataflowBlock)_output).Fault(t.Exception.InnerException);
            if (!_input1.Completion.IsCompleted) _input1.Complete();
            if (!_input2.Completion.IsCompleted) _input2.Complete();
            ClearLists();
        }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted |
            TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
        Task.WhenAll(inputTasks).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // If ALL input blocks succeeded, then the whole block has succeeded
            _output.Complete();
            ClearLists();
        }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted |
            TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    public JoinDependencyBlock(Func<T1, T2, bool> matchPredicate)
        : this(matchPredicate, CancellationToken.None) { }

    public ITargetBlock<T1> Target1 => _input1;
    public ITargetBlock<T2> Target2 => _input2;
    public Task Completion => _output.Completion;

    private void Add1(T1 value1)
    {
        T2 value2;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            var index = _list2.FindIndex(v => _matchPredicate(value1, v));
            if (index < 0)
            {
                // Match not found
                _list1.Add(value1);
                return;
            }
            value2 = _list2[index];
            _list2.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        _output.Post((value1, value2));
    }

    private void Add2(T2 value2)
    {
        T1 value1;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            var index = _list1.FindIndex(v => _matchPredicate(v, value2));
            if (index < 0)
            {
                // Match not found
                _list2.Add(value2);
                return;
            }
            value1 = _list1[index];
            _list1.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        _output.Post((value1, value2));
    }

    private void ClearLists()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _list1.Clear();
            _list2.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void Complete() => _output.Complete();

    public void Fault(Exception exception)
        => ((IDataflowBlock)_output).Fault(exception);

    public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<(T1, T2)> target,
        DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
        => _output.LinkTo(target, linkOptions);

    (T1, T2) ISourceBlock<(T1, T2)>.ConsumeMessage(
        DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<(T1, T2)> target,
        out bool messageConsumed)
        => ((ISourceBlock<(T1, T2)>)_output).ConsumeMessage(
            messageHeader, target, out messageConsumed);

    void ISourceBlock<(T1, T2)>.ReleaseReservation(
        DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<(T1, T2)> target)
        => ((ISourceBlock<(T1, T2)>)_output).ReleaseReservation(
            messageHeader, target);

    bool ISourceBlock<(T1, T2)>.ReserveMessage(
        DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<(T1, T2)> target)
        => ((ISourceBlock<(T1, T2)>)_output).ReserveMessage(
            messageHeader, target);
}
```

Usage example:

```
var joinBlock = new JoinDependencyBlock<FileInfo, FileInfo>((fi1, fi2) =>
{
    // Check if the files are matched
    var name1 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi1.Name);
    var name2 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi2.Name);
    return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(name1, name2);
});
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<(FileInfo, FileInfo)>(pair =>
{
    // Process the matching files
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Item1.Name + " :: " +  pair.Item2.Name);
});
joinBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock);
```