# .NET: do threads waiting on a lock statement enter in the same order with which they blocked?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I've not yet done a specific test on this but in other tests where I needed this behavior it seems to me that indeed threats blocked on a lock statement enter the lock in the same order with which they reached the lock section. Have I been only lucky or is this behavior indeed guaranteed?

**UPDATE**

Indeed using the following code I've been able to confirm that with the lock() statement ordered execution of threads is not guaranteed.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Object objLock = new Object();

    Stopwatch perf = new Stopwatch();
    foreach (var batch in Enumerable.Range(1, 20))
    {
        perf.Restart();

        var sequence = Enumerable.Range(1, 200);
        var tickets = new List<int>();
        var threads = sequence.Select(item =>
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                lock (objLock)
                {
                    tickets.Add(item);
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                }
            });

            Thread.Sleep(10);

            thread.Start();
            return thread;
        }).ToArray();

        foreach (var thread in threads) thread.Join();

        Console.WriteLine($"Batch #{batch}, tickets: {String.Join(", ", tickets)} - " + (tickets.SequenceEqual(sequence) ? "OK" : "NOT FIFO!"));
        Console.WriteLine($"Performance: { perf.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "DONE");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: It's helps to know that `lock` is implemented via [`Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor?view=net-7.0). I've taken a look through and I can't see it making any *documented guarantees* on ordering so I'd advise against writing code that assumes it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does lock() guarantee acquired in order requested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228864/does-lock-guarantee-acquired-in-order-requested). Note: The accepted answer and explaination is about the CLR on Windows. Might be different on other platforms, but even then, one more reason not to depend on any behaviour in this regard.