# Threads synchronization with FIFO order

Tags: c#, multithreading, fifo

I found this helper class:

```
public sealed class QueuedLock
{
    private object innerLock;
    private volatile int ticketsCount = 0;
    private volatile int ticketToRide = 1;

    public QueuedLock()
    {
        innerLock = new Object();
    }

    public void Enter()
    {
        int myTicket = Interlocked.Increment(ref ticketsCount);
        Monitor.Enter(innerLock);
        while (true)
        {

            if (myTicket == ticketToRide)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Monitor.Wait(innerLock);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref ticketToRide);
        Monitor.PulseAll(innerLock);
        Monitor.Exit(innerLock);
    }
}
```

here :

[Is there a synchronization class that guarantee FIFO order in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961869/is-there-a-synchronization-class-that-guarantee-fifo-order-in-c)

It works nice for me but I've just read some comments on this topic about the using of those volatile variables and I am not sure if there is an issue here or not. I understand the code and implemented it in my application in order to do the right job but I admit I can't see a negative impact with this approach in the future, at least, if there is one.

I haven't seen many ways of doing this so it would be nice to have a complete and safe version ready to be used in any situation.

So basically, the question is, can this approach be improved? Does it have any subtle issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also review the [TPL Dataflow](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-2.html) `BufferBlock` class for this purpose:

```
// Hand-off through a BufferBlock<T>
private static BufferBlock<int> m_buffer = new BufferBlock<int>();

// Producer
private static void Producer()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int item = Produce();
        // storing the messages in FIFO queue
        m_buffer.Post(item);
    }
}

// Consumer
private static async Task Consumer()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int item = await m_buffer.ReceiveAsync();
        Process(item);
    }
}

// Main
public static void Main()
{
    var p = Task.Factory.StartNew(Producer);
    var c = Consumer();
    Task.WaitAll(p,c);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For multithreaded FIFO (queue), .NET has provided ConcurrentQueue, I would recommend using ConcurrentQueue instead of using low level locks.

MSDN: [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx)